# mysqli_prepare and sha1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to prepare a statement for login calling the SHA1 function in mysql, but the prepare function keeps returning false

```
 $query = "select user_id, first_name from users where email=? and pass=SHA1(?)";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
```

Passing mysql functions works, as I can use now() without issue. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Why do you send the plain password to your database? Perform the hashing in your PHP code! And you should be using salted hashes...... Anyway, http://php.net/mysqli_error - use this and show us what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run the `sha1()` function in PHP. No reason not too, and it's an easy, valid solution to a problem without an obvious answer.